# How does Orbeon deal with Liferay inherited roles?

Tags: liferay, orbeon

Running 4.1.0.2013040182144-PE on Liferay 6.1.1-CE with Liferay User/Role mapping.

Liferay Scenario:

```
User: Joe
User Group: admin
Role: form-admin
```

With Joe as a member of admin, and admin a member of form-admin, I can successfully set form-based permissions in FB for form-admin. I can't, however, use form-admin within the form for read-only constraints, I need the User to be directly a member of the Role.

Is this a known constraint on Liferay Role pass-through?

Comment: I am not sure: we use Liferay's `PortalUtil.getUser()` to get user information, and the `getRoles()` on that to obtain the roles, see this [source file](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/portlet/liferay/FormRunnerRequestFilter.scala). From there we just use that list of roles.

Comment: Thanks Erik - And that same list is used in both the form-based access decision and populating the pass through variables ($fr-roles)?

Comment: No, I don't know any problems with this. I use frequent user groups to define common permissions: User-X << UserGroup-Y << Role-Z

Comment: Hi Mark - Do you use them for form-based permission, or per-field constraints (read-only, etc.)?

Comment: Yes that's where $fr-roles are coming from.

Comment: Hi Erik - I've re-created the situation with different behaviours for form-based and field-based role mediation. A test form including one output control = string-join($fr-roles,' '). I've tweeted the screen grabs:  Form-based permissions: [link](http://t.co/ozUs1EMFAG). User 1: [link](http://t.co/0xiS3AGJZb). User 2: [link](http://t.co/aIeDhtEldY)

Comment: Thanks for the repro case. I will try to have a look at it.

Comment: Is this one still current?

Comment: Hi Erik - A different scenario with 4.3 compared to 4.2. With 4.2, as discussed above, inherited roles were used for form-based permission, but not per-field constraints. Having looked into it a bit, it apeeared that the form-based permission did a hasUserRole lookup, while the per-field used the populated getRoles. In 4.3 there is consistency between form-based and per-field, but only in the fact that neither now use inherited Roles. Looking on Liferay forums it appears that possibly getRoles only returns regular roles.

Comment: Hi Erik, I should say this isn't a show-stopper for me by any means, as in my current implementation I have control of the privilege set-up, so can put users directly into Roles.